# class attribute with css in jquery

Tags: jquery

I need jquery function do this:

First:

```
<a class="MyClass1 Myclass2 {padding-top:10px;height:20px;}"></a>
```

After calling function:

```
<a class="MyClass1 Myclass2" style="padding-top:10px;height:20px;"><a/>
```

Function must work with all elements

**Edit**

For example: i'm using on the asp.net mvc. Every Module contains different theme properties. This code is Module `partial view` section.

```
<div class="<%=Model.Theme.HeaderClass%>">...content goes here
</div>
<div class="<%=Model.Theme.BodyClass%>">...content goes here</div>
<div class="<%=Model.Theme.PagerClass%>">
<a class="<%=Model.Theme.PagerItemClass%>"> </a>
</div>
```

Comment: doesnt really make sense. why would you have inline CSS styles as part of the class (First example). Not valid HTML.

Comment: It is valid; you can put anything in a class name (although obviously whitespace is ‘special’ as it works a separator). It's certainly massively unwise though.

Comment: I'm designing web modules.Every module contains only class property.for example. HeaderClass,Bodyclass,FooterClass, TitleClass,PagerClass etc... If i'm adding style property those all properties multiply 2. I think that is easy trick

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this, it's horrible.

If you really need to:

```
$('.MyClass1.MyClass2').each(function() {

    // Find classes with name {...}
    //
    var classes= this.className.split(/\s+/g);
    for (var i= classes.length; i-->0;) {
        if (classes[i].slice(0, 1)==='{' && classes[i].slice(-1)==='}') {

            // Remove class from classname list, copy content to style
            //
            var styles= classes.splice(i, 1)[0].slice(1, -1);
            this.className= classes.join(' ');
            $(this).attr(style, styles);
        }
    }
};
```

This is seriously, seriously, a terrible idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery addClass() method, just put your css in class and then add that class to selected element.

http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Comment: read the question. he wants the class removed, and style added, not the other way around.

Comment: He wants to add styling to element. What he is doing is not proper way, because that is not what classes are for.

Comment: I know it's not the proper way, but say that, don't just offer a solution which will confuse the OP without providing reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

First you fetch the link element

```
var link = $('a.Myclass1').filter('Myclass2');
var classes = link.attr('class');
```

then obtain the specific class using regex

```
var styleClass = classes.match(/\{(.+)\}/gi);
```

then remove it from the originlal link and add the style

```
link.removeClass(styleClass).attr('style', styleClass);
```

For multiple classes you can use the .each() method as follows:

```
link.each(function() {
          var classes = this.attr('class');
          var styleClass = classes.match(/{(.+)}/gi);
          this.removeClass(styleClass).attr('style', styleClass);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This -

```
<html>
<head>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var classes = $('a').attr('class').split(' ');
$('a').attr('class',classes[0]+' '+classes[1]);
var style = classes[2].split('{');
$('a').attr('style',style[1]);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a class="MyClass1 Myclass2 {padding-top:10px;height:20px;}" href="#">hi</a>
</body>
</html>
```

This works perfectly the way you want.

Hope it help's.

Answer (score -2):

Dear your can use class with .classname. try this

Comment: Such a crap answer, doesn't even constitute a sentence!